# Determine the point of intersection of a line in the xy- plane

Tags: line, linear-algebra, point

This is a linear algebra question which i am expected to understand before i can start tackling 2D and 3D programming. I am a business application programmer but i am exploring an interest in game programming. I realise that this maybe a simple question to some, so please bear with me.

The line L passes through the points P1 (3, -1, 2) and P2 (1, -2, -1). Determine the point of intersection of L in the xy- plane.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay using those two points you can find the equation of a line (google finding the equation of a line in 3d) from that point on you can equate the equation of a line and the equation of the xy-plane to figure out their intersection (google finding intersection of two planes in 3D).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the z-coordinate of the line as the independent variable, and use the two points to get the formula for the x- and y- coordinates in terms of z.

First, we define the slopes:

```
x_slope=(x2-x1)/(z2-z1);
y_slope=(y2-y1)/(z2-z1);
```

Then we have that:

x-x1=x_slope*(z-z1)

and

y-y1=y_slope*(z-z1)

Setting `z` to 0 and solving for x and y, we get

```
x_plane_coord=x1-(x_slope*z1);
y_plane_coord=y1-(y_slope*z1);
```